# I would like to be able to specify more than one user ID in the search query

Tags: feature-request, search

I can use search query [`user:309650 is:q`](//meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A309650+is%3Aq) to find all questions of user 309650 (actually it's me).

Now I'm changing this query by adding one more id: [`user:309650 user:384512 is:q`](//meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A309650+user%3A384512+is%3Aq).
I expect users to be joined via OR, so I want to see posts of both users - me and @Asinine.

But the actual result is only questions of the last user in the list.

I think this logic should be changed.